# What is the URL to the Sharepoint mapped images folder

Tags: sharepoint

How can I, using the Sharepoint object model, get the URL to an image placed in the mapped images folder?
(added) I am deploying the image as part of a Visual Web Part (named ProgressWebPart for my site).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the server relative url for static images:

```
/_layouts/images/ProgressWebPart/myImage.png
```

While the site relative url (no leading slash) will work, consider what happens when your web part is used in two separate sites. A user visiting these two sites would request the following images:

```
http://server/site1/_layouts/images/ProgressWebPart/myImage.png
http://server/site2/_layouts/images/ProgressWebPart/myImage.png
```

Even though both requests return the exact same file, the browser considers them distinct because they have different urls. By using the server relative url, you ensure that the user only downloads the static file once. If they visit other sites which use your web part then the browser will use the copy inside it's cache saving both time and bandwidth.

Comment: this will not work if there is no site collection located at '/'

Comment: @DennisGeorge - out of curiosity, what version of WSS did you see this on? In SP 2010, all the /_layouts/ requests should invoke IIS's StaticFileHandler so a root site wouldn't be needed.

Comment: I had issues once upon a time with calling /_layouts/* files when there was no root site collection, but that was in 2007. I kind of took it as granted since then, but admittedly haven't tried with 2010. Guess I'll have to set up a test scenario and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the OM to get this - its static and determined how your solution is packaged.

For an example - the default site logo for SharePoint 2010 will be here

_layouts/images/siteIcon.png

So http://yoursite/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png

and htp://yoursite/yoursite/yoursubsite/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be (for my 'ProgressWebPart'):  "_layouts/images/ProgressWebPart/"

As such, loading a PNG file into an Image control can be done in C# with:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.ImageUrl = "_layouts/images/ProgressWebPart/myImage.png";
```